# Nginx conf for prerendering Angular SPA

Tags: angular, nginx, prerender

So I have next configuration for my Angular SPA app:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name idj.rtech.rs;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {

        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        root /var/www/example.com/dist;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name idj.rtech.rs;

        location / {

            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri @prerender;
        }

        location @prerender {
        #proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token YOUR_TOKEN;

        set $prerender 0;
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }
        if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }

        #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        if ($prerender = 1) {

            #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
            set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
            rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
            proxy_pass $prerender;
        }
        if ($prerender = 0) {
            rewrite .* /index.html break;
        }
    }
}
```

But still, my app, when shared on fb or any social media, is just getting static tags, or not tags at all.

Can someone point out where the mistake is, and what I am doing wrong?

Should I also set anything in angular (except dynamic updating tags), or is it just for nginx config?

Also I heard about rendertron, is that easier to setup? What's the nginx conf for that?

***UPDATE 1:***

So hitting: ***curl http://127.0.0.1:3010/https://example.com*** is returning the prerendered page (I am hosting prerender on port 3010)

Hitting ***curl https://example.com*** is returning static angular.

Hitting ***curl -A "twitterbot" https://example.com*** doesn't return anything.

Hitting ***curl -A "twitterbot" -v https://example.com*** returns following:

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Wed, 19 Sep 2018 11:16:54 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the try_files might be serving back the index page when it test the $uri before @prerender is even run. Can you try the following config where I've moved the try_files after the prerender config?

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name idj.rtech.rs;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {

        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        root /var/www/example.com/dist;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name idj.rtech.rs;

        location / {

            #proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token YOUR_TOKEN;

            set $prerender 0;
            if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
                set $prerender 1;
            }
            if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
                set $prerender 1;
            }
            if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
                set $prerender 0;
            }
            if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
                set $prerender 0;
            }

            #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
            resolver 8.8.8.8;

            if ($prerender = 1) {

                #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
                set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
                rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
                proxy_pass $prerender;
            }

            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Comment: Still nothing :( Now, when I go directly to page with some uri (not home page), it reports 404 nginx..

Comment: If you request the homepage with that config like this, what does it return? `curl -A "twitterbot" -v https://example.com`

Comment: Still the same... no response without '-v' and 400 response with -v. I tried both, my conf and your suggested conf

Comment: OK, so I figured out the problem. Rewrite isn't working or I don't know how it should work. It always go to 'service.prerender.io' without any additional info, and it should go to 'service.prerender.io/https://example.com'. So what I did is set up another variable **set $info "/$scheme://$host$request_uri?"** and called **proxy_pass http://$prerender$info**. I know this is a hacky fix, but can you explain why that rewrite is not working?

Comment: Interesting. We haven't heard of any issues with that section of the config from other people. Which version of nginx are you using? I'm glad you were able to set up a workaround. If you continue to see issues, please let us know. support@prerender.io

Comment: Version of nginx is **1.10.3**. Can you explain me a bit how rewrite should work? It should append that as uri in proxy_pass? Also, maybe it has to do because I have 2 server blocks?

Comment: The rewrite should just modify the URL so that it looks like "/https://www.example.com/" and then that should be proxied to the prerender server. So the URL being accessed by nginx would be https://service.prerender.io/https://www.example.com/

Comment: You should submit this config to Nginx as another example for them to list on their [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) page.